# How to remove an element from a string version of html

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

Is there an easy way to remove HTML elements from a string? I would like to remove all the `del` elements from this string:

```
<p>one</p>
<p><del>add</del><ins>four</ins><del>add</del></p>
<p>five</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use DOMParser to turn it into a document, iterate over all `del` elements in the document and remove them. Then turn it back into a string:

```js
const str = `<p>one</p>
<p><del>add</del><ins>four</ins><del>add</del></p>
<p>five</p>`;
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
for (const del of doc.querySelectorAll('del')) {
  del.remove();
}
console.log(doc.body.innerHTML);
```